# Validating ruby installation after install?

Tags: ruby

I've installed Ruby 2.1.1 via source.

I've seen suggestions to type ruby -v, which I assume would show that the binary isn't corrupted, but are there more comprehensive ways to ensure that it's working as expect?  Unit-tests, benchmarks, etc to validate it's functional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `make test` after compiling in the directory you’ve compiled in. (This might actually happen by default, I can’t remember. There’s also `make test-all`, among others.)

Answer (score 1):

`ruby -v` will show you the current version of ruby installed on your machine.

If you want, just create a `hello.rb` with `puts "hello"` and run it using `ruby hello.rb` to check if it is interpreting the ruby code correctly. So you know that its functional.

Comment: How simple it is.. I am not aware of.. I thought I need to check with MATZ for the same.. Lollz :)